# List of valid arguments for the --host parameter on configure files

Tags: c++, c, macos, configure

I am looking for a list of valid arguments I can use when specifying a host on a configure script. For example I could do something like this:

```
./configure --host=alpha-netbsd
```

And that would set the platform and the system, but what other options are there? (I should also specify I am on OSX).

Answer (score 8):

Though being late and incomplete question, hope it may still help someone.

These is no finite list of all possible --host parameter values (configuration names). The combinations are basically infinite, because autoconf implements sort of recognition (guessing) of the configuration name.

You can read the following section in autoconf manual:

- [Autoconf manual - section 26. Cross Compilation with GNU Autotools](http://sourceware.org/autobook/autobook/autobook_toc.html#TOC258)

If you are really interested in implementation of autoconf, you can peek to autoconf repository:

- [/autoconf.git/tree/build-aux/config.sub](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/autoconf.git/tree/build-aux/config.sub)
- /autoconf.git/tree/build-aux/config.guess

LK